# Is this sentence ambiguous? "He told me when to leave."

Tags: ambiguity

"He told me when to leave."

At first sight, I interpreted this sentence as " He told me when I should leave." in case "told" means 'to order."

However, at a second thought, can it be also interpreted as "He told me when he would leave." ? Can "told" have a sense of 'announcing one's thought to others'?

Comment: Yes, _tell_ can mean _inform_, but _He told me when to leave_ cannot mean _He told me when he intended to leave_. The presence of **to** makes it into a command or instruction.

Comment: @KateBunting - could be just advice - e.g. he told me when to leave if I wanted to be sure to catch the bus.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - So are you saying that the sentence _is_  ambiguous?

Comment: @KateBunting - I suppose I am.

Comment: Order: My boss at the bus company told me when to leave (to start my run). Suggestion: my sister told me when to leave for the airport in order to avoid heavy traffic.

Answer (score 1):

The structure *[ "tell" + someone + "to" + infinitive ]* has the function of either giving an order, or giving instructions, but it's always to *someone else*.

That sentence could *include* the speaker if they're leaving together, but could never refer to the time the speaker alone is leaving.

To refer only to the speaker, it would have to be something like:

> He told me when **he has to** to leave.

Of course, this is a completely different grammar structure, and not an order or instruction at all, simply *[ "tell" + somebody + something]*.